# Makefile VAR manipulation for repeated matches

Tags: gnu-make

I want to remove last two chars from a makefile variable.

Example:
WORKING_EXAMPLE:= testeddd

I want a variable that is equal to 'tested' without modifying the original VAR.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$(patsubst %dd,%,$(WORKING_EXAMPLE))